Example of a periodic smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ whose derivatives grow without bound
I'm surprised I can't find this anywhere, but can someone give me an example of a smooth (infinitely differentiable) periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$, but where the supremum of the derivatives is unbounded?
I have tried looking at various Wikipedia pages, and around this site, but so far, no luck.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer each derivative is individually bounded, but that does not mean the sup over all of them is bounded.

@WhileIAm All right, thanks for the clarification.

If $f(x) = \sin(2x)$, then $f'(x) = 2\cos(2x)$, $f''(x) = -4\sin(2x)$, and so on. In general, we have $\|f^{(n)}(x)\|_\infty = 2^n$.
